# Style in CSS rule is missing in Firebug

Tags: css, firebug

What does it mean if the style is missing inside the css rule? It also has no effect on the element.

There's an empty CSS rule in firebug. I know that if a certain style is overwritten, the style is crossed but I'm not sure what it means if the style is missing inside the css rule. I created the rule to affect the padding-top for the  element below.

```
<div id="leadspace-head" class="alternate">
  <div id="leadspace-body">
    <ul id="navigation-trail">
      <li>test</li>
    </ul> 
    <h1 class="small">Title for this page</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the scenario. I have 3 css rules below for the html code above. The first one is inside the body and the other 2 rules can be found in the css file. The 2nd rule overwrites the 3rd rule. I added the 1st rule to overwrite the 2nd rule but it has no effect and shows empty rule in firebug.

CSS within body

```
.landing-page #leadspace-head.alternate #navigation-trail + h1 {
  padding-top: 9px !important;
}
```

CSS in mystyle.css

```
.landing-page #leadspace-head.alternate #navigation-trail + h1 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.landing-page #leadspace-head #navigation-trail + h1 {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "css style within body"? Is it an inline style?

Comment: Style tag is not valid inside the body tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803518/why-cant-style-tags-within-the-html-body-tag-validate-on-w3c

Comment: @tuff are you sure about that?  http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/ or http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/ ...though no browser supports it at this time that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Your styles seem to be overriding each other a lot. You may want to investigate ways in which you can get better use of the inheritance rules in CSS.

That aside, try re-writing your rule to this:

```
#navigation-trail h1.small { padding-top: 9px; }
```

That will specifically target those H1 elements that fall under your #navigation-trail list element.