# Media query not triggering

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to use media queries to change background image and hide content in a division tag if the screen goes beyond 640px.  This doesn't seem to work.  I'm new to this and feel I'm missing something major.

```
    <html>
   <HEAD>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {background-color:black; overflow:none;}
-->
</style>
</HEAD>
<body>
@media screen and (min-width:641px) {
body {background:white;background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/Home-Background-2013a.gif');}
div.desktop {visibility:hidden;}
}
<div class="desktop" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px; z-index:1">
<img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/mobile1.jpg" width="100%" height=auto>
<img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/mobile2.jpg"  width=100% height=auto>
<img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/mobile3.jpg"  width=100% height=auto>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS isn't working because its not contained with-in style tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {background-color:black; overflow:none;}


-->

@media (min-width:641px) {
    body {
        background:white;background-image:url('http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/Home-Background-2013a.gif');}
        div.desktop {visibility:hidden;
    }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="desktop" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px; z-index:1">
<img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/mobile1.jpg" width="100%" height=auto>
<img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/mobile2.jpg"  width=100% height=auto>
<img border="0" src="http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/oberers-flowers/mobile3.jpg"  width=100% height=auto>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Can you explain the difference between media screen and (min-width:641px) and media (min-width:641px)

Comment: I believe the @media screen will get the width of the screen, you can use media screen in this code I was just quickly typing the answer and must have forgot to include it.

Comment: To answer your other comment, you can it just gets super messy and hard to code, by putting the code into a styles.css file you can easily manage your html and css. To link them just put in your header; <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

Answer (score 0):

For one, you're missing a `<style>` tag around your media query there. Also, I'd recommend against using inline styles (i.e. `style=""` attribute tags in your HTML). Keep all your CSS in one place, preferably a separate CSS file you can link to in your head tag.

Also, make sure you keep your media queries declared after your other CSS for those selectors. Whatever comes last will take precedent!

Comment: So is there any reason you couldn't do a separate style tag at the end of the document or link to a css file at the very end of a document?

Comment: It's most common by far to put `<style>` tags in the head of the HTML file. This used to be required but was relaxed with the HTML5 spec. Now, you can put `<style>` tags anywhere in the HTML, but it's easier to run into CSS issues if you do. [See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910296/does-css-have-to-be-defined-within-head-tags]