# jQuery works in IE 8 but not Firefox 22

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

My navbar works fine in IE 8 but not FF 22 (I'm not really concerned with other browsers atm) I've reviewed the related questions but haven't found a solution, it would seem its usually FF that works and not IE. I've also tried using the window load function and the issue persists. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\wamp\www\jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.navigation li').hover(
                        function () {
                            $('ul', this).fadeIn();
                        },
                        function () {
                            $('ul', this).fadeOut();
                        }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        STYLING....
    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="navigation">
        ALL MY NAVIGATION....
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You ought to put `<style>` in the `<head>` element. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1303472/2231440) for a few reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URIs don't use backslashes. IE may treat them nicely, but no other browser will. Also, if you're running this on a webserver, just use an absolute URL:

```
src="/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
```

Comment: I figured I was making a noob mistake, thank you so very much, I will accept your answer in 10 minutes, I've learned something today!!