# How to insert CSS code into a page if I can't insert it into head tag? Only inline mode?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have to insert some CSS style into a Plain HTML module inside a CMS. The problem is that I have no access to the template so I can't insert the CSS into a .css style file.

I had thought that I could use the  tag (that would enable me to insert the CSS styles directly in the HTML) but reading online seems to me that I can only insert it into the  tag and I can't do it because I have not access to the template code.

So my questions are:

1. Can I use the  tag outside of the  tag?
2. If not the only solution is to use inline CSS or can I try something else?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does <STYLE> have to be in the <HEAD> of an HTML document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303416/does-style-have-to-be-in-the-head-of-an-html-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a style tag anywhere in the page, for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My page</title>
</head><body>
<style type="text/css">
    * some styles *
</style>
</body></html>
```

so assuming your CMS allows Full HTML markup you should just be able to insert your styles using this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) element everywhere, not just inside the `head`.

Additionally, you can make it scoped in some browsers to limit the range of its effects (see [relevant specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-style-scoped)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the following tutorial:[Click](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)
Also dystroy is right you can place  tag anywhere.Such placing of style tag is not allowed by HTML DTD and so it wont be validated but most browsers support it so it will do.All the best.