# Hover class not working on a div

Tags: html, css, hover

I am unable to get the hover class to work on any element within my html document. We are trying to make anyone of the 4 squares to disappear, aka display:none; Here is a demo of my site. Let me know if you can spot what my error is. Thank you in advance!

https://c9.io/riotgear66/day1/workspace/sams/html/index.html

Comment: Your inline styles are overwriting your hover styles.

Comment: on a side note. don't put `<style>` tags inside the `<body>`. Put it in between the `<head>` tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303416/does-style-have-to-be-in-the-head-of-an-html-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with trying to hide something when it is hovered is that as soon as it is hidden, it is no longer hovered over and it comes back.  So you can't do that.

You could use `opacity: 0` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/bYNmh/

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

If you set `display:none` on an element over which you are hovering, you then cannot hover over a nonexistent element. This is what causes the flickering. To do what you would like to do you have to explicitly change the background in the .css for the element.