# I cannot get a CSS box to show up in my HTML webpage, what changes should I make?

Tags: html, css, box

I want the words "Check Out" to show up in a CSS box, however I am not able to do this. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Box</title>
</head>

<style>
.boxed {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px blue;
    margin: 0;
}

.shadow {
position: relative;
max-width: 270px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0, 0, 0.2)
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="boxed">Check Out</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note: you seem to be missing a closing `</html>` bracket.

Answer (score 0):

1. The style tags go inside the head tags.
2. like Brendan mentioned, you were missing the closing html tag.
3. Also, for the border you just had

   ```
   .boxed { border: 5px blue; }
   ```

You need to specify which type of border, like is it solid, dotted, dashed?

So I added

```
.boxed { border: 5px solid blue; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Box</title>
    <style>
    .boxed {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 5px solid blue;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .shadow {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 270px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0, 0, 0.2)
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="boxed">Check Out</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Style tag can go anywhere. Some people actually recommend putting at the bottom so the HTML can load first.

Comment: @Adelphia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303416/does-style-have-to-be-in-the-head-of-an-html-document

Comment: Well to be fair, putting it atthe bottom is only recommended when using external style.

Comment: @Adelphia according to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) *If the "scoped" attribute is not used, each <style> tag must be located in the head section."*

Comment: What the standard says and what the browsers do aren't always the same. Has anyone ever had an issue with styles in the body not working.. let's be real guys

Comment: @Adelphia Browsers are very forgiving. You can also leave out many end tags, the browser will automatically add them when it sees you end a containing tag, but no one would recommend writing HTML like that.

Comment: I saw it in a BootStrap article actually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the third part of a border.
A border is line thickness(px) color, and type: dashed, solid, transparent and a lot of others.
Google it.

Answer (score 0):

The div is visible. the only thing you missed was a background (pretty, pretty) and maybe if you can't see it on screen is because of it's display, position, size, etc.

if you want to see it go to http://jsfiddle.net/rgqfjb1v/

also check if you have that last `</html>`

I also added solid for the border, like this: `border: 5px solid blue;`

'YOU MISSED THE SOLID OPTION'

Comment: I have </html>, it just didn't copy/paste for some reason. Thanks though.