# Embed multiple <style> tags into a single html page

Tags: html, css

I want to preface this with the understanding that I'm aware this is sub-optimal for web design but my hands are tied.

I am working within my organization of my company to add documentation in an html format through a form field.

The html I am coding will be, essentially, inserted into the rest of the page's body and I don't have access to the style sheets or to the style tags in the header.

Right now I am embedding my css in the html but I would like to have a little bit cleaner code so, to the question at hand.

Is there a way to embed a second section under style tags where I can define IDs and classes in the body.  I've tried to just put style tags in the body but it's conflicting with the header of the overall page.

Please let me know if more clarification is needed and thank you, before the fact, for any help!

Comment: From looking at comments to answers here It looks like you are coming across [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issues. Use developer tool (F12) in chrome or FireBug for Firefox to inspect the elements you are targeting to see what rules are affecting them.

Comment: Specificty, quick and dirty intro. Given the following html `<div><div class="bob">Bob</div></div>` if your style tags in the body have `.bob` and the style tags in the header have `div .bob` the header version will be applied as it is more specific. You need your styles to be at least as specific, if not more so, than those in the head.

Comment: Also make sure that the styles you are adding end up in the HTML! View the page source and see if your style is there. I've know CMS systems to strip out `<style>` sections from the body.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to embed a second section under style tags where I can define IDs and classes in the body. I've tried to just put style tags in the body but it's conflicting with the header of the overall page.

Multiple style tags are ok. When you have multiple style tags, [the cascade rule applies](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/), so you just need to make sure your selectors have higher specificity than the page's default style.

The second issue is of where you put the style tag. Strictly speaking, the `<style>` tag is supposed to go in the `<head>`, but in practice [all browsers will apply `<style>` anywhere in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303416/does-style-have-to-be-in-the-head-of-an-html-document). Having style in body, the page will not validate, however it will work fine.

Comment: OK, I'll have to play around with that, unfortunately I won't be able to work on it until tomorrow.  The other thing I tried was adding '!important' to my css but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this, defining a `<style>...</style>` block within the `HTML` and it's working fine across the browsers I've tested (Firefox, IE10, Chrome).

Comment: Yes, I had already tested and it works fine to embed that in the body.  But it does not work when I add the same HTML into the form.  When I look at the overall page source, there is a previously existing style block previously that I think is taking priority over mine.  I'm unable to make changes to that so I can't just add my classes and id's up there.

Comment: You can do something to make your rules more specific  Maybe try wrapping your html in a DIV with a certain id like `<div id="my_content">...` and then your CSS rules could take that into account: `<style> div.my_content input { color: red; }...`

Comment: Just make sure you use `div#my_content` if using an id!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "*it's conflicting with the header of the overall page*"? Is there a PHP error saying that their is an output and header can't be set (so the system seems like using ob_start/ob_flush)

Normaly following should work:

```
<body>
    <style>
        .class {
           border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

Maybe some of the CSS given in the header using !important and make it impossible to overwrite or you just missing some attributes so it looks like you not changing anything at all.

You probaly could use this technik to load stylesheet dynamically into the header: [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

```
var ss = document.createElement("link");
ss.type = "text/css";
ss.rel = "stylesheet";
ss.href = "style.css";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
```

or you creating a style element and fill it with styles, but this will be more complex, because you have to do it completly with Javascript and at some point it sucks.. also to have it clean a extra file would be perfect solution.

I like a directoy `css` or `stylesheets` (based on the directory pattern I am following, either short terms like `img`, `css`, `js` or long terms like `scripts`, `images`, `stylesheets`) and a `default.css` inside. It's your decision what you call it.

Comment: I don't have access to the header.  I'm basically inputting something similar to a blog post into a pre-existing page that's part of my company's intranet.  I've tried to embed a style block into the body but it is not functioning when placed into the form.  The same code works fine on its own if I just open it in browser as a .html object.

Comment: This looks like a bad implementation of your organization or they have a workaround for things like that. Speak with your manager and tell them, that you can't add stylesheets, because something is blocking and ask if there is something aviable from the core code. Maybe they check for `<style>` and change it to `&lt;style&gt;`? I mean it works outsite the given system, so it have to be the system and we know less that you about the system. You **have** to ask your manager or something who knows about it or at least get enough rights to modify the core framework to add another style.