# How to make a simple recognizing game using may symbols

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to this and still learning haha so go easy on me.

I am trying to make a simple recognizing game using map symbols as the images.
I have got the start button when clicked will ask you a question but cannot seem to get a random picture to appear as well. I also what the grey stars to light up every time the user selects the right button/symbol.
 Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <style> 
        body{ background-color: lightblue; }
    </style>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>OS Map Symbols</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <p> <input onclick="btnStart(); displayRandomImage();" type="button" value="Start" /> </p> 

        <input id="btnTrain" type="button" value="Train Station" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnBus" type="button" value="Bus Station" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnYouth" type="button" value="Youth Hostel" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnFootpath" type="button" value="FootPath" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnBridle" type="button" value="Bridleway" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnWorship" type="button" value="Place of Worship" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnHouse" type="button" value="Public House" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnCar" type="button" value="Car Park" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnRoad" type="button" value="Road" disabled="disabled"/>
        <input id="btnPillar" type="button" value="Triangulation Pillar" disabled="disabled"/>

        <center> <p> <p id="paragrapgh"> </p> </center> 
        <center> <div class="contents" id="content"></div> </center>

        <img id="imgTrain.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_TS.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgBus.jpg"  img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_BS.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgYouth.jpg"  img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_YH.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgFootpath.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_FP.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgBridle.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_BW.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgWorship.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_PW.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgHouse.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_PH.jpg" width="100" height="100"  style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgCar.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_CP.jpg" width="100" height="100"  style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgRoad.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_RD.jpg" width="100" height="100"  style="display:none;"/>
        <img id="imgPillar.jpg" img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_TP.jpg" width="100" height="100"  style="display:none;"/>

        <img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\star-g.gif" img id="imgStar1" />
        <img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\star-g.gif" img id="imgStar2" />
        <img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\star-g.gif" img id="imgStar3" />
        <img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\star-g.gif" img id="imgStar4" />
        <img src="C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\star-g.gif" img id="imgStar5" />
        </body>     
    </html>
<script> 
    function btnStart() {
        var x = document.getElementById("paragrapgh");
        x.style.fontSize = "25px";
        x.style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("paragrapgh").innerHTML = "What Is This Symbol?";
    }
    function displayRandomImage(){
        var Images1 = new Array();
        Images1[0]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_TS.jpg"
        Images1[1]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_BS.jpg"
        Images1[2]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_YH.jpg"
        Images1[3]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_BW.jpg"
        Images1[4]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_PH.jpg"
        Images1[5]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_RD.jpg" 
        Images1[6]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_FP.jpg"
        Images1[7]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_PW.jpg" 
        Images1[8]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_CP.jpg"
        Images1[9]= "C:\Users\ekene\OneDrive\Pictures\MapSym_TP.jpg"

        var random = Images1[Math.floor(Math.random() * Images1.length)];
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = random;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. The issue you're encountering can be solved using the [`addEventListener`](https://jsfiddle.net/qx41kgs3/) method of connecting events to elements. In this case, adding an `id` to your start button and firing the events when clicked would look like this

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qx41kgs3/)**

**HTML**

```
<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start" />
```

**JS**

```
var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
startButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    btnStart();
    displayRandomImage();
});
```

It's worth mentioning you have a number of `HTML` syntax issues including unclosed tags, [style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303472/648350) and [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/648350) tags outside of the `html` element, [using `.` in `id` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/648350), and using deprecated tags like [`center`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303472/648350).

Unfortunately, because you have locally linked images, im not sure if you're asking how to make the gif items animate again ([Can you control GIF animation with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2385203/648350)) or if you're asking about swapping image src using js ([Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag))

From a coding perspective, the way you're going about trying to link up images to the buttons could be made far simpler for yourself by starting with a JS object, and generating items from there, especially as you have a consistent path to images. Something like this: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qx41kgs3/1/)