# Header and footer not getting adjusted

Tags: html, css, jsp

> Footer.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>    
ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: black;
width:1230px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
margin:20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}
.fa-twitter:hover {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}
.fa-youtube:hover {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}
.fa-instagram:hover {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
</style>
<ul>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
<li style="float:left;"><a>Copyright &copy;</a></li>
```

> Header.html

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
li{
    float:left
}
li a {
    display:block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FirstPage.jsp">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.jsp">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.jsp">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="Books.jsp">BOOKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="Register.jsp" id="l1">REGISTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="Login.jsp" style="float:right;margin:20px 0 0 500px">LOGIN</a></li>
  </ul>
```

> FirstPage.jsp

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Library Management</title>

<style>

</style>
</head>
<jsp:include page="header.html"/>
<body>
I don't know
</body>
<jsp:include page="footer.html"/>
</html>
```

I have been trying to add the header and footer file in the FirstPage file but the output of FirstPage is showing the footer file all over the page and no header file.

Answer (score 0):

`header` and `footer` html should be inside the `<body>` body. Also move your `<style>` inside the `<head>` tag or put in the external css file.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Library Management</title>

    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <jsp:include page="header.html"/>
     I don't know
    <jsp:include page="footer.html"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Your styles are completely messed up. I've commented some css in two `ul` places. Here's a quick fix,

```html
<html>
<head>

<title>Library Management</title>

<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
/*
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
*/
    z-index: 1;
}
li{
    float:left
}
li a {
    display:block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FirstPage.jsp">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.jsp">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.jsp">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="Books.jsp">BOOKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="Register.jsp" id="l1">REGISTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="Login.jsp" style="float:right;margin:20px 0 0 500px">LOGIN</a></li>
  </ul>
I don't know

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>    
ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: black;
width:1230px;
/*
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
*/
}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
margin:20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}
.fa-twitter:hover {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}
.fa-youtube:hover {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}
.fa-instagram:hover {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
</style>
<ul>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
<li style="float:right;"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
<li style="float:left;"><a>Copyright &copy;</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Putting inside the body doesn't work. What do you mean by putting the style inside the head tag?

Comment: All styles are should be placed inside the `<head>` as per w3c standards.

Comment: Issue is your styles is completely messed up.  Updated my answer

Comment: So i should give them id and then add styles??\

Comment: Yes, you can use `id` or `class`

Comment: I used it but now whole screen is black!!

Comment: did you remove `position: absolute` and `position: relative` from two `ul` styles?

Comment: if I remove those two the tabs appear but they are not placed correctly.

Comment: No, the styles should be placed exactly after the `<head>`, not inside it.

Comment: @JatinBisht You need to find a work around to fix the problem. Because I don't know what exactly you are building. I just pointed out where the issue is.

Comment: @FotisGrigorakis No, that's definitely wrong as per W3C standards. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303416/does-style-have-to-be-in-the-head-of-an-html-document

Comment: it is temporarily solved. I just used stylesheets and it worked.