# History API state code disables website functionality

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I run the following code in facebook.com (either with Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey). The code hides the left navigation menu, available in [your general wall](https://www.facebook.com/).

### My problem:

The code works, but after executing it I cannot access my [faceook conversations page](https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/).

When navigating to the conversations page by clicking the messages icon, then, "See all in messenger", my conversations page appears as a **blank page**.

[image]

---

### My code:

```
let utilityFunc = ()=>{
    let run = (run)=>{
        setInterval( ()=>{
            document.querySelectorAll('#left_nav_section_nodes, #pagelet_ego_pane, .ego_section').forEach((e)=>{
                e.remove();
            });
        }, 500);
    };

    let pS = window.history.pushState;
    let rS = window.history.replaceState;

    window.history.pushState = (a, b, url)=>{
        run(url);
        pS.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    window.history.replaceState = (a, b, url)=>{
        run(url);
        rS.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};

utilityFunc();
```

### My question

Why would this code cause that?

Comment: i dont know but your code doesn't seem to work. when are you injecting this?

Comment: why do you need to override `replaceState` and `pushState`? why not just add css rules using your selector?

Comment: Odd... It should work. Especially if you just use the `qSA` and `forEach()` (you could test to see). Try executing with Greasemonkey please. Regarding injecting CSS. I know this option but I want to make sure I understand why it didn't work with this way above (which I used before knowing how to inject CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this.

### Way 1:

I consulted a senior JS programmer about this and this is the solution he gave me. The code behaves basically the same but without the problem:

```
let utilityFunc = ()=>{
    let run = ()=>{
        setInterval( ()=>{
            document.querySelectorAll('#left_nav_section_nodes, #pagelet_ego_pane, .ego_section').forEach((e)=> {
                e.remove();
            });
            // alert('All selectors are valid so far and if they weren't, this entire module was failing');
        }, 250);
    };

    let pS = window.history.pushState.bind(window.history);
    let rS = window.history.replaceState.bind(window.history);

    window.history.pushState = (...args)=>{
        run();
        pS(...args);
    };

    window.history.replaceState = (...args)=>{
        run();
        rS(...args);
    };
};

utilityFunc();
```

He told me that to understand this solution, one needs to learn about `call()`, `apply()` and `bind()` concepts ([here's an article to cover these](https://medium.com/@omergoldberg/javascript-call-apply-and-bind-e5c27301f7bb)), and to understand [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

### Way 2 - the original way I could take:

One can use CSS injection to inject CSS so to manipulate the selected elements via CSS.

See [this SE QA session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013891/adding-or-injecting-more-than-one-row-of-css-with-vanilla-javascript-in-an-array) for more data (see answers by Dan Krieger and user8551674).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the ID `#timeline_tab_content` wraps the conversation page. If it does then you need to find a more specific ID you can use to hide all the content on other pages without interfering with the conversation page. Something tells me Facebook uses that ID `#timeline_tab_content` on the conversations page since it acts as a timeline when you scroll up or down.