# table.tableize-table r function works well in .html, but not display in Gmail through MIMEText

Tags: python, html, gmail, html-email, mime

Newbe working on html. I got below settings in .html, and it works as expected when opening the file in a browser (chrom/safari).

(in browser)[image: output seen opened in browser]--> (failed in gmail)
[image: undesired content received in gmail]

However, when I use MIMEText to send the same html content, it fails: none of the color code features are preserved. It does not matter that attribute I tried to edit in table.tableizer-table, font-size, `border`, none works when sent in email.

```
<html><body>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
        .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
        .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #009452;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
        .tableizer-firstrow td {
        background-color: #009452;
        color: #FFF;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    </style>

    <table class="tableizer-table">

    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#104E8B; color: #ffffff;"><td align="center" rowspan="1" colspan="5" ><strong>RECORD <strong></td></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th style="background-color: #CCC;color: #FFF;">GOOD COMPANY</th><th>EMAIL</th><th>PHONE</th><th>ADDRESS</th></tr>
    <tr><td>company2</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">0</td><td>100</td><td>1st Ave</td></tr>
    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th style="background-color: #CCC;color: #FFF;">BAD COMPANY</th><th>EMAIL</th><th>PHONE</th><th>ADDRESS</th></tr>
    <tr><td>company2</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">0</td><td>212</td><td>Fifth Ave</td></tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working primarily on python and email is sent as below:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(one_email_html, 'html')])
receiver = 'aaa@gmail.com'
sender_email = 'bbb@gmail.com'
print('Type in password')
password = input()
message["Subject"] = subject
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver

# Create secure connection with server and send email
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(
        sender_email, receiver, message.as_string()
    )
```

where `one_email_html` is the """string""" of the html content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be placing the `<style>` section inside `<head>...</head>` tags.

Second, you should inline all embedded styles. This is why this works: `<tr style="background-color:#104E8B; color: #ffffff;">`, but your classes don't. Some email clients, such as some forms of Gmail, and most desktop and webmail environments, do not support embedded styles at all (styles within `<style>`).

Third, perhaps you need to use the full hex, rather than shortened hex codes. So `<th style="background-color: #CCC;color: #FFF;">` becomes: `<th style="background-color: #CCCCCC;color: #FFFFFF;">`, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much, moving into `<head>...</head>` makes it works for both my personal  Gmail and work mail powered by Google. It's quite helpful to get you reminded about the correct usage of <style>.

Comment: For`<tr style="background-color:#104E8B; color: #ffffff;">`,  in my understanding is only control cells locally, in the case `<style>` does not work, it will be very tedious to set color, and esp. **border** for every cell?  I am wondering if <style> is the only scalable way.

Comment: I see this as  a [good overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275805/4595242) on <style> usage

Comment: It may be a good general guide, but email *does not follow specs, standards, or anything*. Each email client runs its own unique set of rules. What you might like to do to remove tedium is to set it up using `<style>s` and then use an inlining tool to automate that part (google for such services - there are a few).